# MKL error when using IMSL

Tags: fortran, intel, intel-mkl, imsl

I am using IMSL with Intel Virtual Fortran with MKL. I tried to use a routine from IMSL. It was compiled fine, but when I try to execute the file it came up with an error saying:

```
MKL ERROR: Parameter 7 was incorrect on entry to SGEEVX

*** TERMINAL ERROR 2 from EVCRG.  The required storage cannot be allocated.
***          The specified N may be too large, where N = 1064682127.
```

The following is the code I am using:

```
PROGRAM test_evcrg
include 'link_fnl_static.h'  
!DEC$ OBJCOMMENT lib:'libiomp5mt.lib'

IMPLICIT NONE
REAL, Dimension(2,2) :: p,vr
REAL, Dimension(2) :: w

p = RESHAPE([0.7, 0.3, 0.5,0.5],[2,2])

CALL EVCRG (p,w,vr) 

WRITE (*,*), w
WRITE (*,*)
WRITE (*,*), vr

END PROGRAM test_evcrg
```

How can I fix this problem?

AFTER I ADDED 
      USE EVCRG_INT

IT GIVES THE ERROR INFOMATION:

```
    test_evcrg.f90(14): error #6285: There is no matching specific subroutine for this generic subroutine call. [EVCRG]
    CALL EVCRG(p,w,vr)
---------^
    compilation aborted for test_evcrg.f90 (code 1)
```

THANKS.

In the IMSL USER'S GUIDE, it says:

```
   FORTRAN 90 Interface
   Generic:  CALL EVCRG (A, EVAL, EVEC [,…])
   Specific:  The specific interface names are S_EVCRG and D_EVCRG.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know IMSL enough, but I think there is a mismatch of interfaces. Because you do not `use` any IMSL module, you are not using the Fortran 90 interface, but the Fortran 77 interface, which requires more arguments. See [IMSL manual](http://www.roguewave.com/Portals/0/products/imsl-numerical-libraries/fortran-library/docs/6.0/math/default.htm?turl=evcrg.htm). Either `use` the module, or change the call to something like `CALL EVCRG (2, p, 2,w, vr, 2)`.

The use statement you can use is probably `USE numerical_libraries`.

---- EDIT ----

It means, that adding the use was the good thing. Now it exposes, that there really was an error in the call. The arguments are wrong.  Arguments 2 and 3, i.e. EVAL and EVEC must be `COMPLEX`!

Comment: Thank you very much. I think the interface is correct, I am using the Fortran 90 interface. I did make another try: I added USE EVCRG_INT into the code, which I think follows the naming convension of the library. It gave a new error:test_evcrg (I added the new information in my post).